# Netbeans generated jar file not working

Tags: java, netbeans

I have the initial code generated by netbeans in the new JFrame Form which shows the following output when run:-[image]

But, when I run the jar file in the dist folder, I get the following:-
[image]

How, to solve this problem? Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Not able to see the error completely. What I understand is , you are getting classloading issues. I expect, you would have created a normal jar with class path entries in MANIFEST file. Try creating a executable jar or runnable jar file or provide required dependencies using -cp argument to java command.

Can you paste the whole error in text in OP?

Comment: @AbhijithNagarajan View it large in http://i.stack.imgur.com/VS5R2.png

Comment: post the error in the form of text...

Comment: make sure u have added necessary class-file/libraries in the classpath

Comment: @codeMan, where to add such details?

Comment: @BenLind refer to the so question & answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2132505/setting-java-classpath-to-load-a-class-file

Answer (score 0):

You will need to edit your build.xml so that all your used libraries are included in the build process.
This will look something like this in build.xml:

```
<target name="-post-jar">
    <echo>Adding jar: ${reference.myMissingJar.jar}</echo>
    <jar update="true" destfile="${dist.jar}">
        <zipfileset src="${reference.myMissingJar.jar}"/>
    </jar>
    <mkdir dir="bin"/>
    <copy file="${dist.jar}" todir="bin" description="Copy jar file."/>
 </target>
```

The problem is that while you try to run it in netbeans, the IDE knows about all those nifty libs you use. When using a single jar, that is something different altogether.

Alternativly you might want to state the locations of your used libs in your classpath parameter.

Comment: When you look inside the manifest of your jar, does it have a class name somewhere? If so, is the path to it describing the correct package?

Answer (score 0):

In netbeans do a Clean and build project (shift + f11)
[image: Netbeans clean and build project]
if that doesnt help please post more details.
Are u using external libs?